# write a script in mql4 to edit symbol window

Tags: mql4

I am trying to write my first script in MQL4 and had hopefully a few basic questions.

1) I am aware that I can write a script and drag and drop it on a symbol window to execute the script. I was wondering though if there was a way to reference a symbol window through the code?

Is it just like the code below,

```
WindowHandle("EURUSD", PERIOD_M1)
```

2) Is there anyway to specify the time horizon of a symbol window. For example say I want the symbol window to show me the EURUSD 1 minute data from 4th March 2012 10:10 am to 4th December 2012 4pm? Can you also specify the number of bars to show on the chart at anyone time?

3) Can you draw a line on the chart using a script? I think I read you cannot - that you would need to write a custom indicator? I understand using a script however that you can annotate the chart with a text object though.

Answer (score 0):

### A3: Yes, you can

### A2: No, any code is sub-ordinated to the pre-set MT4.Graph instance

In other words, your code ( any MQL4 ( well, valid as far as Build 711 )) cannot moderate the outer-container ( the MT4.Graph ), be it zoom, Y-scale, changing it's Period and other "given" features, some of which may be editable by user ( but not by the code )

### A1: No, but ... might be you read about some

This is rather dangerous zone. Imagine a MT4 Terminal, that has a live-session, if there were such `WindowHandle( "EURUSD", PERIOD_M1 )` and if there were six graphs for [EURUSD,M1]. Which way should the identification / execution follow? No, this is left intentionally as a "Human-step", because executing any kind of code is associated with risks and may create huge if not fatal losses ( as the code runs blind and deaf and VERY FAST ).

While there are some dirty techniques to identify/swap MT4-"window" these techniques are highly dependent on O/S services. For normal use, I would dare rely on any of those I have read about so far.